# closure, variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, closures

```
def f():                                                                        
    a = 0                                                                       
    def g():                                                                    
        a = a + 1                                                               
        return a                                                                
    return g                                                                    

s = f()                                                                         
print s()
```

When I run this code I get:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

can't figure out why.
Many thanks.

Comment: Is the error on line 4 (`a = a + 1`)?

Comment: You are assigning to it, so it is not a non-local name. Is this Python 3 or 2?

Comment: Python sees `a` as a local name because you assign to it in the `g()` function. In Python 3 you'd use the `nonlocal` keyword to tell the interpreter explicitly to make it a closure, but in Python 2 your only option is to avoid assigning to `a` directly. Mutate a shared list object or a function attribute instead.

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters! Have an awesome day!

Comment: `return a + 1 ` would work.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I needed it to work as a counter when i call it, but never mind

Comment: Standard way to do this without nonlocal is to put "def g(a=a)", i.e., use the keyword with the same name, which ensures binding. I don't know if you wanted to change the value of a in the enclosing scope or not...